# ownProps is empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

AddOrUpdateProduct.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getCategories } from "../../redux/actions/CategoryActions";
import { saveProduct } from "../../redux/actions/ProductActions";
import ProductDetail from "./ProductDetail";
import { validate } from "@babel/types";

function AddOrUpdateProduct({
  products,
  categories=[],
  getProducts,
  getCategories,
  saveProduct,
  history,
  ...props
}) {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({ ...props.product });
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!categories||categories.length === 0 || !Array.isArray(categories)) {
      categories = getCategories();
      console.log(categories)
    }
    setProduct({ ...props.product });
  }, [props.product]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setProduct(previousProduct => ({
      ...previousProduct,
      [name]: name === "categoryId" ? parseInt(value, 10) : value
    }));

    validate(name, value);
  }

  function validate(name, value) {
    if (name === "productName" && value === "") {
      setErrors(previousErrors => ({
        ...previousErrors,
        productName: "Ürün ismi olmalıdır"
      }));
    } else {
      setErrors(previousErrors => ({
        ...previousErrors,
        productName: ""
      }));
    }
  }

  function handleSave(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    saveProduct(product).then(() => {
      history.push("/");
    });
  }
  return (
    <ProductDetail
      product={product}
      categories={categories}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onSave={handleSave}
      errors={errors}
    />
  );
}

export function getProductById(products, productId) {
  let product = products.find(product => product.id === productId) || null;
  return product;
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const productId = ownProps.match.params.productId;
  const product =
    productId && state.productListReducer.length > 0
      ? getProductById(state.productListReducer, productId)
      : {};
  return {
    product,
    products: state.productListReducer,
    categories: state.categoryListReducer
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getCategories,
  saveProduct
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(AddOrUpdateProduct);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container } from "reactstrap"
import Navi from '../navi/Navi';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import {Route,Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import CartDetail from '../cart/CartDetail';
import AddOrUpdateProduct from '../products/AddOrUpdateProduct';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {//params or props is equal {}
  return (
    <Container>
      <Navi></Navi>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard/>} />
        <Route path="/product" element={<Dashboard/>} />
        <Route path="/cart" element={<CartDetail/>} />
        <Route path="/saveproduct/:productId" element={<AddOrUpdateProduct/>} />
        <Route path="/saveproduct" element={<AddOrUpdateProduct/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Even if I try to use `useParams()` or reveive props to do `{...props}` or `{...params}` in `App.js`, it doesn't work. I can't send data from `App.js`.

This is error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'params')
> at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]

All libraries are latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` there are no route props, e.g. no `history`, `location`, or `match` props. It should be clear by the usage that there are no additional props being passed to the `AddOrUpdateProduct` component.

> ```
> <Route
>   path="/saveproduct/:productId"
>   element={<AddOrUpdateProduct />} // <-- no extraneous props passed here
> />
> ```

Use the `useNavigate`, `useLocation`, and `useParams` hooks instead.

In this case you'll also want to update to use current `react-redux` code by using the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks instead of the dated `connect` Higher Order Component.

Example should be close to what you are looking for:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getCategories } from "../../redux/actions/CategoryActions";
import { saveProduct } from "../../redux/actions/ProductActions";
import ProductDetail from "./ProductDetail";
import { validate } from "@babel/types";

function AddOrUpdateProduct() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { productId } = useParams();

  const products = useSelector(state => state.productListReducer);
  const categories = useSelector(state => state.categoryListReducer);

  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!categories?.length) {
      dispatch(getCategories());
    }
  }, [dispatch, categories]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId && products.length) {
      const selectedProduct = getProductById(products, productId);
      setProduct(selectedProduct);
    }
  }, [productId]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setProduct(previousProduct => ({
      ...previousProduct,
      [name]: name === "categoryId" ? parseInt(value, 10) : value
    }));

    validate(name, value);
  }

  function validate(name, value) {
    setErrors(previousErrors => ({
      ...previousErrors,
      productName: name === "productName" && !value
        ? "Ürün ismi olmalıdır"
        : ""
    }));
  }

  function handleSave(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(saveProduct(product))
      .then(() => {
        navigate("/");
      });
  }
  return (
    <ProductDetail
      product={product}
      categories={categories}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onSave={handleSave}
      errors={errors}
    />
  );
}

export function getProductById(products, productId) {
  return products.find(product => product.id === productId) || null
}

export default AddOrUpdateProduct;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but now, I got Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable. error. So I solve this but it causes to endless loop. How can I solve? Thank you for your attention

Comment: @user14919564 Sorry, I wrote all that in a plain text editor so I didn't have the benefit of any static code analysis or linting. Which `const` variable is reassigned? I wonder if it's an issue related to the duplication of the selected state into local component state.

Comment: const categories

Comment: @user14919564 Ah, yes, certainly remove the `categories =` bit from the dispatch of the `getCategories` action.

Comment: I got the error : Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Comment: @user14919564 Like I said, it seems odd to duplicate some redux state locally and then only update the local cache. Is this the intended design/expected behavior, or do you actually want to update the redux state? I'll update the answer to memoize the `selectedProduct` value so it won't cause a dependency render loop.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new in React. I am trying to wrote a hook. this code control inputs and handle change and save the product. Actually I am not sure what I did. Just I am trying to learn

Comment: @user14919564 No worries, we all started out new. If the question is addressed then I wish you good luck. Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252359/discussion-between-user14919564-and-drew-reese).